# Marie Curie fellowship future possibilities

Tags: funding, europe, contract, marie-curie

I am a non-european who started a PhD with a Marie Curie fellowship program, however, I have had problems with my supervisor and I was not able to find another supervisor during my first semester, so I am considering terminating my contract. My question is if I will have some problem or issue by trying to initiate another contract under support of Marie Curie fellowship in other university or how this situation will affect me?

Comment: I'm going to suppose that the administrators of the fellowship program could give you better guidance.

Answer (score 1):

The MSCA project you proposed was designed to work with your current supervisor, so terminating your contract will end your MSCA fellowship (and your financial support).

If I remember correctly, even a large part of the MSCA proposal consists of describing why your supervisor and you are a good match and how the two-way-transfer of knowledge will benefit the two of you. So you cannot simply quit and find another one.

Nevertheless, having won an MSCA fellowship will greatly benefit your CV.

Comment: Well, this supervisor doesn't want to work with me and me neither due to his behaviors. So, this means that I will be able to get another contract with Marie Curie in the future???

Comment: Your Marie Curie contract is bound to your project, which is bound to your supervisor. Changing your project/supervisor terminates the contract and you will have to apply again in the next upcoming call.